# calculate leaves from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a leave table like this:

```
**employeeId    action      type       effective_date**
   1            leave       paid        2016-01-15
   2            leave       unpaid      2016-01-16
   1            return      return       2016-01-17
   2            return      return       2016-01-17
```

I tried this query:

```
$query = (select * from table where employeeId = "$empID" && type = "$type");
```

after this I am stuck; actually I want:

```
where Empid = 1 && action = leave && type = paid orderby effective_date

$i=0;
$j=$i+1;
$leave =0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $leave = $row['effective_date'][$i] - $row['effective_date'][$j];
    $i+1;
    $j+1;
    $leaves = $leaves+$leave;
}
```

Could you help me to correct this? Or is there better way to calculate leave?

Comment: start by trying to run your desired query in phpmyadmin, or whatever sql editor you're using.  and do the calculations in your query, not in PHP.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but in terms of cost why not use an existing time management system? http://www.kimai.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have to give space between `ORDER` and `BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee`
    WHERE `employeeId`='1'
    AND   `action` = 'leave'
    AND   `type` = 'paid'
ORDER BY  `effective_date` ASC
```

**Output**

```
+------------+--------+------+---------------------------+
| employeeId | action | type |            effective_date |
+------------+--------+------+---------------------------+
|          1 |  leave | paid | January, 15 2016 00:00:00 |
+------------+--------+------+---------------------------+
```

**Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bac3/3**

And this will give you number of leaves:

```
SELECT `employeeId`, COUNT(*) AS `NumLeaves` FROM `employee`
    WHERE `employeeId`='1'
    AND   `action` = 'leave'
    AND   `type` = 'paid'
GROUP BY `employeeId`
ORDER BY  `effective_date` ASC
```

**Output**

```
+------------+-----------+
| employeeId | NumLeaves |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

**Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bac3/6**

Comment: Number of leaves should be return effective_date - leave effictive_date - re date = total leave days